# How to manage Azure DevOps security on level deeper than Project level?

Tags: azure-devops, permissions

For our instance of Azure DevOps we're looking to manage security settings on a level where we can provide end users access to the individual work items/features without granting full permission on a Project level. Is there a way we can manage these permissions in such a way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can restrict access to work items and features based on Area Paths.

Best practice would be to use different teams and then allow permissions to specific area paths.

See the following Azure DevOps Learn Modules for complete information:

- [Manage Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/manage-teams?view=azure-devops)
- [Work Tracking Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops)